# Wiki Template question

Tags: form, wiki, template

I posted a similar issue before but I was not very clear so Ill try my best to explain what I am trying to achieve. 
I am a Student working for a large company, The team I am working with has these document templates they use for different projects. they are just Word documents with headings, sections, and tittles they can not change. They are only allowed to add information in the sections, text and images.

I was asked to try to replicate the same document template but online and using Sharepoint 2010. I though I could create forms, but this did not work.

I THINK the best way to approach this issue is using a wiki, is there a way to create a template so if a user wants to create a new wiki page, they do not get a blank page but rather a template with sections for them to add the text and images they want?

or is there another way to approach this issue?

any help is very aprecciated, thanks in advance. 
E.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/set-a-file-template-for-a-document-or-form-library-HA010377912.aspx

You'll want to create several document libraries with templates for each type of project. It doesn't sound like they want a wiki-type solution, but rather collections of word documents. The above link will walk you through how to do this.

Good luck!